# Typing with anonymous vs. non anonymous functions in haskell

Tags: haskell

Why does this identity compile when I type it

```
f = (\x -> x) :: a -> a
```

but this one does not?

```
f x = x :: a -> a
```

When I just write

```
f x = x
```

And load it into ghci and type :t f I receive

```
f :: p -> p
```

So, shouldn't it be the same thing?

The error I receive is

> Couldn't match expected type ‘a1 -> a1’ with actual type ‘p’
>           because type variable ‘a1’ would escape its scope
>         This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
>           an expression type signature:
>             forall a1. a1 -> a1

I already googled about the rigid, skolem thing and the error but it only gave me more questions.

Originally I wanted to write a function that takes two inputs and returns the first one, which only worked with the anonymous function. So I seem to lack some understanding when it comes to lambdas and typing. I am still at the beginning of learning Haskell.

```
f = (\x y -> x) :: a -> b -> a
```

Comment: The type annotation only applies to the RHS of the definition, not the entire definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You apply the type signature `:: a -> a` to `x`, *not* to `f`. You can add a type signature with:

```
f :: a -> a; f x = x
```

However, you can not specify that `x` is of type `:: a` anyway, since that `a` is a different type variable than the `a` in the outer type signature. You can enable the [**`ScopedTypeVariables`** [ghc-doc]](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables) extension, to use type variables defined in an outer scope, like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

f :: forall a . a -> a
f x = x :: a
```

Comment: Ah, I was typing the x. That was what was confusing me.. I saw the :: typing at the end of the function and thought this is some way of shorthand to type the function. Thank you!